# Spring Services - Avoiding recursive loops between services

Tags: java, spring, architecture, jhipster, n-tier-architecture

I am working on a JHipser project (http://www.jhipster.tech/).

So far I have been conforming the following "default" architecture.

[image]

**Description** :
The typescript client makes rest calls which are handled by the resource classes.
To handle rest calls the resource classes call a service class.  The service class will call one or more repo classes to retrieve entities from the database.

**Architectural Design Issue** :
The issue that I am now facing is that business logic in one service class needs to be used by other service classes.

At first, i simply used spring constructor injection, to inject the required service classes.  This worked fine initially (in the first few service classes) but then I started to get recursive issues - some service classes were including other service classes that included the first class etc.. so there was recursion that spring couldn't handle.)

So now I want to redesign the way I have done this and introduce a solution that will serve for quite a while.

I am asking for suggestions or best practice in this area ?

Here is am thinking of doing.  I'd be interested to here feedback on what others have done and feedback on my proposed approach.

[image]

My proposal is to introduce the concept of levels to the service layer.
Level 1 service classes will be called by the resource classes.
Level x service classes will call the repo classes.
Levels 1 to x-1 can only call service classes that are below it (e.g. AbcServiceClassL1 can call XyxServiceClassL2 but not vice versa).

How many levels I have will depend on the complexity of each business area.

What do you think about this design ?
Have other faced similar issues ?
What has your design been ?

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts on this.

Kind regards,
Fergal.

Comment: This is where pure CRUD approach does not  scale and is only the beginning, rather than aggregating CRUD repositories per entity all way up to REST, have you considered refactoring your domain model using DDD aggregates? In clear having one repository per aggregate rather than per entity? Searching for talks by Oliver Gierke about DDD and Spring data/REST is highly recommended.